# Do powers/feats/features that buff a character's healing work with Skald's Aura?

Tags: dnd-4e, bard, aura

> **Skald's Aura:** [...] you or any ally in the aura can use a minor action to spend a healing surge
>   and regain 1 d6 additional hit points. Alternatively, you or any ally
>   can use a minor action to allow an adjacent ally to spend a healing
>   surge and regain the additional hit points.

Is it correct that e.g. a fighter who heals himself using Skald's Aura gains no benefit from a Skald with any of these

> **Mark of Healing (feat):** Whenever you use a healing power on an ally or use Heal to
>   allow an ally to spend his or her second wind, that ally can also make a saving throw.
>
> **Healer's Brooch (item) Property:** When you use a power that enables you or an
>   ally to regain hit points, add the brooch’s enhancement bonus to the
>   hit points gained.
>
> **Master Skald Level 16 (feature):** Whenever you restore hit
>   points to a creature with a healing power, the creature regains 4
>   additional hit points.

(and most others)? As far as I can tell, it has to be the Skald himself who actively performs the healing (standing adjacent to the recipient) in order for any of these types of effects to take place (making most of these choices a bit useless for the class).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Healers's Brooch definitely works as it's only pre-req is the regaining of hit points.

The other two you mention are predicated on the `healing` keyword. Skald's Aura has this keyword so they both work.

The basic rule is to determine whether or not the power/feat/etc specifically mandates the `healing` keyword and whether or not the power/item/etc you are using contains that keyword. So, mark of healing requires a power to have that keyword, healer's brooch does not.

The next question would be whether or not the skald has to be spending the action for the power to take effect. I'd argue that you are still *using* the power even if someone else is expending the action.

Comment: Is the healing action allowed by Skald's Aura a power? The Skald's Aura is a power that creates a zone in which actions can be taken to heal. If Skald's Aura healing actions are not powers, then none of the listed buffs help.

Comment: @SimonWithers I'd argue that the actions taking are "using the power"

Comment: Simon Withers' point was exactly my concern! Since there have been no more answers, I guess there's no official ruling on the issue. Skald's Aura is pretty crippled compared to the encounter heals of other leaders if it needs to be the Skald doing the active healing, so I think the ruling that the Skald is USING the power is reasonable. I'll make sure to check with our GM.